# Shopware 6 customer logout using an API endpoint

Tags: authentication, logout, endpoint, shopware

I'm building a website using the Shopware 6 API, but I'm stuck on the logout functionality.
The login using the API endpoint is working (I think), cause I'm getting the context-token, like its written in the docs.

```
const endpoint = "http://localhost/store-api/account/login"

{
    "apiAlias": "array_struct",
    "contextToken": "a6Vln3kANKtqyKBetH6cZscVyk3uoibT",
    "redirectUrl": null
}
```

My problem is, I don't really understand how the logout is handled in the backend.
I am using the endpoint from the documentation to logout as a customer, but it doesn't work, I get the message further below:

[Dev Documentation](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/0e95542f7b261-log-out-a-customer)

```
const endpointLogout = "http://localhost/store-api/account/logout"

const optionsLogout =  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json, application/json',
      'sw-access-key': 'qkHmlDAwiyhmloFfohmmREi5bO52mb5N'
    },
    body: undefined
  };
```

I get the same message in Postman and the IDE.
How the backend know which customer should be logged out, because the only thing in the header is the general api access key for the sales-channel and not the customer specific context-token.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "403",
            "code": "CHECKOUT__CUSTOMER_NOT_LOGGED_IN",
            "title": "Forbidden",
            "detail": "Customer is not logged in.",
            "meta": {
                "parameters": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to change the sw-access-key in the headers to the sw-context-token without any luck.

Shopware is running on Docker (dockware-dev) locally in the version 6.4.20.1

Sorry if the text is hard to read, english not my native language. I would appreciate any help.